# Remove empty ns attribute from SOAP request using EndpointInterceptor

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap

There is this legacy system which is sending SOAP requests with an empty namespace attribute causing fields values to be null, when namespace attribute is removed while testing from SOAP UI, it work fine.

This is what problematic SOAP request looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ADD xmlns="http://www.cc.com/ws">
            <ID xmlns="">dummy</ID>
            <PWD xmlns="">password</PWD>
        </ADD>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried by adding an interceptor using `addInterceptors` method of `WsConfigurerAdapter`, code of which is pasted below, but it doesn't work

```
@Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
    
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = ((SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest()).getSaajMessage();
    SOAPBody body = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();
    
    Iterator<SOAPBodyElement> it = body.getChildElements();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Object node = it.next();
        if (!isTextNode(node)) {
            com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.BodyElement1_1Impl e = 
                    (com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.BodyElement1_1Impl) node;
            
            Iterator<SOAPBodyElement> subItr = e.getChildElements();
            while(subItr.hasNext()) {
                Object subNode = subItr.next();
                if(subNode instanceof com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl) {
                    SOAPElement el = (SOAPElement) subNode;
                
                    el.removeAttribute("xmlns");
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a namespace declaration in XML is not an attribute. Don't be confused by the similar syntax!

So I would not expect `e.removeAttribute` to do anything, because there is no attribute with the name `xmlns`.

What you actually need to do is to *change the name* of the element, e.g. using its [setElementQName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPElement.html#setElementQName-javax.xml.namespace.QName-) method.

```java
@Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
    
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = ((SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest()).getSaajMessage();
    SOAPBody body = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();
    
    Iterator<SOAPBodyElement> it = body.getChildElements();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Object node = it.next();
        if (!isTextNode(node)) {
            com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.BodyElement1_1Impl e = 
                    (com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.BodyElement1_1Impl) node;
            
            Iterator<SOAPBodyElement> subItr = e.getChildElements();
            while(subItr.hasNext()) {
                Object subNode = subItr.next();
                if(subNode instanceof com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl) {
                    SOAPElement el = (SOAPElement) subNode;                
                    el.setElementQName(
                        new QName(
                            e.getElementName().getURI(), 
                            el.getElementName().getLocalName()
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
    return true;
}
```